# Why do i get a circular reference exception when calling to_json on an ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3 (beta 3 on 1.8.7), when calling to_json on a relation i get a circular reference exception. Converting that relation to an array first, and THEN calling to_json works.

Code That fails:

Model.where().to_json (Where model is any model in your Rails 3 app)

Code that works:

Model.where().to_a.to_json

This can be reproed on the console.

Has anyone else run in to this? Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into this. Looks like it was resolved in this commit:

http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/eb04408a20628a49296e0859425940b39a83ec63

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, couldn't fix it but found out how to avoid it, with the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  response = @product.to_xml
  format.xml  { render :xml  => response }
  format.json { render :json => Hash.from_xml( response ).to_json }
end
```

The idea here is to generate the XML format of the response, then Hash it, then format it to JSON.

This approach gave me more than expected, since now JSON formatted results have exactly the same data as XML formatted ones.